# Package nuget not installed correctly

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I installed a package with Nuget on VisualStudio, but in the Packages of my project, this message appears in the extension I installed. What should I do to make it work properly?
The extension is: `ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar`

> Package 'ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.LATEST 1.0.6' was restored
> using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of
> the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package
> may not be fully compatible with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Different projects can target different frameworks. Your project is targeting `netstandard2.0`, but the package you're depending on doesn't support any `netstandard` framework.

The only solutions are to not depend on that package, or to change the target framework of your project to `net472` or one of the others in the list in the error message.

Comment: You can manually change it in your csproj file. But be aware it may not be an appropriate thing to do - netcore, netframework and netstandard projects can all depend on netstandard projects, but only netcore projects can depend on netcore projects, and only netframework projects can depend on netframework projects (this is the whole problem in your question). So changing your project to something other than netstandard limits the projects that can depend on yours